# How to create cshtml file automatically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using MVC 5 and want to create cshtml file automatically like a forum.

I have created a page to allow user posting new thread. When user submits, I will get the data from textarea and insert into database. I have done that control.

My question is: How to create a cshtml file to load data from database and display it automatically?

Example: I post a new thread with the title is: **Here is my title**. When I click submit, it will be converted to `<a href="/NewThread/Here-is-my-title">Here is my title</a>`

That mean: the controller **NewThread** and the view **Here-is-my-title.cshtml** had been created successfully.

Can you tell me how to do that?

p/s: I hope this is a clearly question. thank you!!!

Comment: You will not have to create a new cshtml file. When create you post and it's stored in the database, you can reference that post by calling its Id/ThreadTitle. Creating new cshtml files will be a bad idea.

Comment: @SHammelburg Thanks. If I do that, the URL cannot be changed. Because I only load data and display it, not take an action. So, the URL will be kept.

Answer (score 0):

```
  If u use the entity framework model....u dont need to create a cshtml file ...it is created automatically

Follow this steps

1. Right Click The controller

2. Goto Add Controller

3. Then Choose The "MVC5 Controller With Views using Entity Framework"

there u can automatically create the controller and view
```